# Complexity of "half cycle"

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

I'm working on the following problem:

*HALFCYCLE (HALFC):*

**Input:**

A directed graph $G = (V,E)$.

**Output:**

Whether the longest cycle in $G$ has length $ \lfloor |V|/2 \rfloor$.

> Prove that if $\mathsf{PH} \ne \mathsf{coNP}$ then HALFCYCLE is not NP-complete.

I have no idea how to solve this implication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show that if HALFCYCLE is NP-complete then $\mathsf{NP}=\mathsf{coNP}$, and so the polynomial hierarchy collapses to NP.

How do you prove that if HALFCYCLE is NP-complete then $\mathsf{NP}=\mathsf{coNP}$?
There are two options:

1. Show that coSAT reduces to HALFCYCLE. Since HALFCYCLE is NP-complete, in particular it is in NP, and so coSAT is in NP, implying NP=coNP.
2. Show that HALFCYCLE is in coNP. Since HALFCYCLE is NP-hard, in particular SAT reduces to HALFCYCLE, and so SAT is in coNP, implying NP=coNP.

(You can replace SAT with any NP-hard problem, and coSAT with any coNP-hard problem.)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help Yuval Filmus. :) I'll try to solve it.

Comment: Well, by choosing the first option and using the exercise 3, claim 2 in the following link http://cse.iitkgp.ac.in/~abhij/course/theory/CC/Spring04/ct2Sol.pdf, in theory, it should be enough to prove NP = co-NP.  Are you agreeing with me?

Comment: Part of doing math is realizing when you have proved something.